# Scrolling in a div

Tags: css, html, scroll

As you can see in the image below, I have a red div at the size of the "screen", what I want to is to make content scrollable in that area only. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

The whole pad's css:

```
#mainWindow{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image:url("../images/mainWindow.png");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    padding:55px 60px 95px 65px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position: relative;
}
```

Screen's css:

```
#screen{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `overflow-y: scroll` to your `#mainWindow` CSS declaration.

(Or alternatively to your `#screen` CSS declaration.)

Comment: or if you don't want scroll bars *all* the time, use `overflow-y:auto`.  This will add scrollbars when necessary

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be in the #screen and it works. Another question, is there a way to hide the scroll bar at the right side?

Answer (score 2):

Set the overflow property of that div.

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#divID {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

...might do the trick. If you need the parent element to not scroll, you could maybe set it like:

```
#divID {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: "Thanks, but it has to be in the #screen and it works. Another question, is there a way to hide the scroll bar at the right side?"

Just make a containing div with overflow: hidden, and size it to cover the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS tag you're looking for is 'overflow'