# Specify Scroll Bar Location

Tags: html, css

I have a web page that I am working on. It has a fixed header and footer so that only the body element's will scroll. When a page is pulled up that need a scroll bar, the scroll bar pushes the elements in the header and footer to the left. Is there a way to make it so that the scroll bar only appears in the "scroll-able" section of the web page and does not reach vertically into the header and footer elements?

Example (the "S" represents the scroll bar only being in the body element):

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| This is the Header                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| This is the body with scroll-able content.              S|
|                                                         S|
|                                                         S|
|                                                         S|
|                                                         S|
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| This is the Footer                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you need to see any html or anything let me know. I wasn't sure if it would be necessary for this question.

**UPDATE** Here is a simplified version of my attempt. The header and footer stay in position like  I want them to, but the body still doesn't scroll:

[Link to Attempt on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2QKhF/3/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrolling in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940258/scrolling-in-a-div)

Comment: sorry, i did look at that, but it didn't help solve my problem. I tried the answers that were posted but nothing worked right so that's why i posted this.

Comment: Please include the code you tried in your question, and let us know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the height of your header and footer can be fixed:

```
#header, #footer, #body {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
}

#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
}

#body {
    top: 20px; /* #header height */
    bottom: 20px; /* #footer height */
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Look up the [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property for controlling scrolling.

Comment: do the positions have to be there? The header and footers are still good after doing this, but the middle section of the page doesn't scroll all the way down. I have (essentially) five table rows that need to be displayed, but only and a small portion of the 3rd shows between the header and footer. after editing this to contain the scroll bar in the body element, it doesnt scroll enough to even get the 3rd row in view. it barely moves at all.

Comment: @Jason9024, see [my fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/2QKhF/6/). Pretty much as I described, but I removed `.scrollable {height: 100%;}` It is unnecessary when you also specify `top` and `bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/2QKhF/)

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="scrollable">

    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
}
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    top:0;
}
.footer {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    bottom:0;
}
.scrollable {
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% - 100px);
    background:yellow;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Might want to check that Jason9024's browser supports [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: it doesnt matter, i only used `calc` to make it pretty for the eye. might as well define the layout differently, my point was that he needs to set `overflow-y:scroll;` to the scrollable area and `overflow:hidden;` to the body to hide the automatic page scrollbars

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/2QKhF/) - I made the changes to the css and as you can see in this j fiddle, it didnt work.

Comment: the problem is because the scrollable div height is set to 100%, while you need to resize it to fit the area between the header and the footer. if your targeted browsers are able to utilize `calc()` then you simply use calc to calculate 100% - 300px which is heights of header and footer combined, and set overflow to scroll. here is a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2QKhF/4/ you can also check browser compatibility in the following chart: http://caniuse.com/calc as you can see, most current browsers support calc().